# Why does PHP's iconv need setlocale?

Tags: php, locale, iconv

I'm currently trying to remove all special characters and accents from an UTF-8 string by turning them into their equivalent ASCII character if possible.

So I'm simply using this code:

```
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $input);
```

The problem is that for example the word "début" turns into "dbut" instead of "debut".
To make it work, I need to add a call to setlocale, like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $input);
```

And I don't understand why. I thought UTF-8 and ASCII were always the same, whatever locale you use.

EDIT: I didn't mean UTF-8 equals ASCII, I meant UTF-8 always equals UTF-8 and ASCII always equals ASCII

Comment: ASCII and UTF-8 aint the same. UTF-8 is bigger by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

The subset of UTF-8 that overlaps with ASCII (which is code points 0-127) is indeed identical with ASCII. However, accented latin characters are not part of the ASCII character set and if you don't `setlocale` yourself, the system's default locale (which evidently does not contain these accented characters) is used to get a character set to work with.

In general, `iconv` can be a little iffy; this is mentioned in the [introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php) of the extension:

> This module contains an interface to iconv character set conversion
>   facility. With this module, you can turn a string represented by a
>   local character set into the one represented by another character set,
>   which may be the Unicode character set. Supported character sets
>   depend on the iconv implementation of your system. **Note that the iconv
>   function on some systems may not work as you expect.** In such case,
>   it'd be a good idea to install the GNU libiconv library. It will
>   most likely end up with more consistent results.